# Vim netrw - differences between Explore commands?

Tags: vim, netrw

I'm a little confused by the netrw documentation on the Explore command variants.  In particular, I don't understand how `Sexplore` (split & explore) differs from `Hexplore` / how `Sexplore!` differs from `Vexplore`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of those commands is explained in the following help sections:

```
:help netrw-:Hexplore
:help netrw-:Sexplore
:help netrw-:Vexplore
```

The difference between `:Sexplore` and `:Hexplore[!]` is that the former respects your `splitbelow` and `splitright` settings while the latter ignores them.

Same story for `:Sexplore!` which respects your settings, and `:Vexplore[!]` which doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  I think the help sections on those probably could have been written more clearly.